# Items of recyclerview gets invisble after resuming Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, onresume

it seems like nobody else have this problem because I didn't find any answer to this. My problem is that the recyclerview doesn't show his items after resuming the activity a second time. To get the items back visible I must click or scroll anywhere on the recyclerview. I really don't know if the items are invisible, the noteList is empty or if there other Problems. Maybe it's only the structure. I am not sure. Here is a snippet of my code:
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener, NoteListAdapter.NotesAdapterListener {

private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
public FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
private FirebaseFirestore db;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;
public NoteListAdapter adapter;
private List<Note> notesList;

private ListenerRegistration firestoreListener;
private RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvNoteList);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    notesList = new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setPersistenceEnabled(true).build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

    Query query = db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>().setQuery(query, Note.class).build();
    adapter = new NoteListAdapter(notesList, response, MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);

    recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CustomRecyclerViewDivider(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, MainActivity.this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    firestoreListener = db.collection("users").document(firebase_user_uid).collection("notes")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.e("LOL", "Listen failed!", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc : documentSnapshots) {
                        Note note = doc.toObject(Note.class);
                        note.setId(doc.getId());
                        notesList.add(note);
                    }
                }
            });

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerViewTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            if (notesList != null || notesList.size() <= 0) {
                Note note = notesList.get(position);
                updateNote(note);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    adapter.startListening();
    setAlarms();

    invalidateOptionsMenu();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
    navEmail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);

    username  = sharedPreferences.getString("display_name", "");
    email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");

    if (username == null || email == null  || username.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {
        email = mFirebaseUser.getEmail().toString();
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("email", email).apply();
    }

    navUsername.setText(username);
    navEmail.setText(email);
}}
```

Comment: Does it work when `Activity` creates?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Yes, perfectly.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Still same Problem. Maybe I shouldn't load the notesList not everytime new I resume the Activity? But when I make this I would have the Problem I had before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056917/getting-indexoutofboundsexception-only-when-resume-activity

Comment: The question is.. why would you need to reload the data every time the `Activity` reappears?  Firebase is a realtime Database--You can get snapshots when the data has been changed.

Comment: @Barns  I don't need to load the Items every time new. Please look at my Question a few hours before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056917/getting-indexoutofboundsexception-only-when-resume-activity This guys said me to do everything with Firebase in onResume instead of onCreate. And it worked(the app didn't crash anymore after resuming the activity). But now I have this Problem.

Comment: There is a lot about your code I think you should rethink (re-design). But there is also some code that is missing--Where are the methods `adapter.startListening()` and `adapter.stopListening()` defined? What do they do? What is `updateNote(note)`. Why have you added `MainActivity.this` twice to the `Adapter` constructor::  `adapter = new NoteListAdapter(notesList, response, MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);` ?  And as I said earlier--Firebase is a realtime DB. Let it do the work.

Comment: @Barns `adapter.startListening()` and 'adapter.stopListening()' are methods from firebase. The 'updateNote(note)'  function is not important for the resuming error. Mhh, yes I will change the Adapter that it will be only one time `MainActivity.this`. But this didn't solved my Problem unfortunately.

Comment: "... Adapter that it will be only one time MainActivity.this. But this didn't solved my Problem unfortunately. "  I never said it would solve your issue, but clean code helps track down issues.

Comment: @Barns Okay but I still thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following codes. Place `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` (and `notifyDataSetChanged()` after) inside `runOnUiThread()` (Or wherever you update-change or doing sth on `Adapter`):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do something on UiThread

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Because it effects-changes the UI, i was able to show it like this with `runOnUiThread()` method.

Comment: @marcelo.wdrb You should take a look at the codes from sample again : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52057174/4409113 it seems like there are few thing (like `onStart()` method, `if (adapter != null)` & etc) you should consider first then trying to do other things on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.:)